# How can I match words A or B or nothing on regex.h, C?

Tags: c, regex

Development's environment is regex.h on C. It's POSIX regex. 
 And I putted a REG_EXTENDED option. (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html)

Here is PostgreSQL's some syntax. [] part can be ignore or use word. () part have to use one word. '|' means OR.

```
SET [SESSION|LOCAL] SEARCH_PATH (TO|=) (SCHEMA|'SCHEMA'|"SCHEMA");
```

For example, this syntax can be like this.

```
#1: SET SEARCH_PATH TO SCHEMA;
#2: SET SESSION SEARCH_PATH = "SCHEMA";
```

I've wanted to parse schema's name. But I can't make correct regex.

I made this regex When I ignored omitted part. don't considerate about case. I already made ignore case option.

```
^\\s*set\\s+search_path\\s+(to|=)\\s+['\"]?([a-z0-9_$$]?+)['\"]?
```

But it was not working if I putted session or local. So I fixed this regex little bit. But I couldn't make sure to match corrected sentences. This is what I tried.

```
^\\s*set\\s+(session\\s+|local\\s+)?search_path\\s+(to|=)\\s+['\"]?([a-z0-9_$$]?+)['\"]?
```

So I hope to make regex what can be matched correct syntax.

Edit:
I tested this and working well what I wanted. You can see what I tried on this web page. https://regex101.com/r/5zclS7/3
But on C, it's not working.

Comment: Try it like this `^\\s*set\\s+(?:(?:session|local)\\s+)?search_path\\s+(?:to|=)\\s+(['\"]?)[A-Z0-9_$]+\\1;`  https://regex101.com/r/UgV8N5/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird brackets are just symbol of syntax. They are not using real sentences. I am trying to make regex on your link.

Comment: Note that SQL syntax is not a regular language...

Comment: @pmg it's POSIX regex.

Comment: @DDukDDak99 Parsing SQL with regex is a bad idea, but the problem you describe is probably related to the use of alternation in the BRE POSIX, try compiling the pattern with `REG_EXTENDED` option. There may be other issues, please add the code you are using to run the regex. Also, FYI: no need to double `$` in the bracket expression. Use just `[a-z0-9_$]+`. Ah, look, there is `?+`. Please replace it with `?`.

Comment: Actually, `[a-z0-9_$$]?+` must be `[a-z0-9_$]+`. Try fixing it, and it should work.